# Best way to test a rails view helper without rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actionview

I am making a gem that defines some framework agnostic helpers for generating html. 
Testing under Sinatra is trivial. But what do I need to test heplers by rails erb and haml rendering without having to require the full stack?

I guess at some point I have to require 'action_view' and 'action_view/renderer/renderer'

Comment: i think it would be best to create a sub-rails-project with the full stack and test within that one